# Android Google map in fragment tab with sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps, android-fragments

I am using android google map in fragment 1 tab with extracting latlog from my sqlite database.

I have used spinner to select option and button in my fragment.

I have total 3 fragments.

fragment 1 is "NormalMapFragment"
fragment 2 is "HeatMapFragment"
fragment 3 is "ClusterMapFragment"

I am getting error at this:

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();
}
```

The errors is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onResume()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.bharat.plantnow.Maps.NormalMapFragment.onResume(NormalMapFragment.java:169)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2005)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1572)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:545)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17554)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:607)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:674)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17554)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17554)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17554)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17554)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17554)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2871)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17554)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5891)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

My Normal map .xml file find below:

```
 tools:context="com.example.bharat.plantnow.Maps.fragments.NormalMapFragment">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/textheading2"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:id="@+id/et_search"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:hint="@string/hint_treecond"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
        android:background="#ffd8dcde"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Map"
        android:id="@+id/MapButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#ffb73a3b"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:onClick="onSearch" />
</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    />
```

My NormalMapFragment .java: I have used Mapview, Button,Spinner, sqlite db.
Let me know where i am getting wrong, and correct according...

```
public class NormalMapFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

MapView mMapView;


private Button btMap;
private TreeData db;
private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

private Spinner inputSearch;
String[] conditions = {"All Locations",
        "Balanced",
        "Healthy",
        "Imbalance",
        "Dangerous",
        "Transplanted",
        "Dieseased"
};



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.normalmap, container,false);

    inputSearch = (Spinner)v. findViewById(R.id.et_search);
    ArrayAdapter adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.spinner_text_layout, conditions);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    inputSearch.setAdapter(adapter1);
    inputSearch.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);



    btMap = (Button)v. findViewById(R.id.MapButton);


    btMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String search = String.valueOf(inputSearch.getSelectedItem()).toString();
            mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
            mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          //  mMapView.onResume();

            try {
                MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mMap = mMapView.getMap();

            mMap.clear();
            // SQLite database handler
            db = new TreeData(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            Cursor c = db.getSelectedLocations(search);
            if(c.getCount()>0){


                c.moveToFirst();

                do {

                    double latitude1 = c.getDouble(c
                            .getColumnIndex(SQLiteHandler.KEY_TLATITUDE));
                    double longitude1 = c.getDouble(c
                            .getColumnIndex(SQLiteHandler.KEY_TLONGITUDE));

                    String marker = c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(SQLiteHandler.KEY_TreeID));

                    LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude1, longitude1);

                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(marker));

                    // Moving CameraPosition to last clicked position
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));

                    // Setting the zoom level in the map on last position is clicked
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));

                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(4));


                } while (c.moveToNext());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Locations of " + search + " trees", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else if(search.equals("All Locations")) {
                double latitude = 0;
                double longitude = 0;
                String mark;

                // SQLite database handler
                db = new TreeData(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

                Cursor locationCursor = db.getLocations();

                locationCursor.moveToFirst();

                do {
                    latitude = locationCursor.getDouble(locationCursor
                            .getColumnIndex(SQLiteHandler.KEY_TLATITUDE));
                    longitude = locationCursor.getDouble(locationCursor
                            .getColumnIndex(SQLiteHandler.KEY_TLONGITUDE));

                    mark = locationCursor.getString(locationCursor
                            .getColumnIndex(SQLiteHandler.KEY_TreeID));

                    LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(mark));


                } while (locationCursor.moveToNext());

                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "All trees locations ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                db.close();

            }
            else{

                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Location are not available ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });

    return v;
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mMapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mMapView.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}
```

}

Comment: Are you using an emulator?

Comment: initialized `mMapView` outside `button onClick(....)`

Comment: Thanks MD..Working perfectly!.  I want to use onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item).to select the SATELLITE view.Where should i add. In fragment or in mainactivity